# Non standard paper size when creating PDF from MD in pandoc

Tags: pandoc

This question is kind of an extension to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455078/specifying-papersize-for-md-to-pdf-conversion
so for specifying paper size I can use command like
`pandoc README.md -o readme.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V papersize:a4`
But this works for standard paper sizes, like A4, for example.
I would like, however, to create a PDF which will be printed on continuous tape paper with page size of 8.25 x 12 inch.

How do I use such size?
I tried looking for answer in the links provided in answers and comments for that question and I quickly got lost as I'm completely unfamilliar with tex stuff.

I do have such custom size available on the print dialog options in my system (Debian 10, LXDE), I added it under name "Tape_12" but I guess that it's completely irrelevant for this task.